# Double vertices while Retopologizing

Tags: mesh, vertices, mirror, topology, subdivision-surface

Why is this happening?
I am using subsurf,mirror and shrink modifier

Thanks
[image]

Comment: What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without more information, but it looks like you just have a broken mesh.

Simply select the two vertices and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to merge them together to create a quad:

[image]

---

---

***EDIT:*** As far as closing up the back seam...

Just create Tris on the bottom by selecting three vertices and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

With the ***Merge Vertices*** option enabled, it will automatically connect both sides of the ***Mirror Modifier***:

[image]

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RightClick</kbd> to select a series of vertices at the seam and just pull them over to connect since you've enabled ***Merge***.

[image]

Comment: I know but what is causing that?because I have a lot of them

Comment: mabye because when I unite some of them i select all 4 corners and then F?

Comment: @VladIlisan - Yes, that can definitely create the illusion that they're joined but the process of modifying the mesh shows that they're unconnected.

Comment: @VladIlisan - if you could upload your .blend I could take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/    You could also remove doubles before modifying.

Comment: thanks man!Removing doubles did the trick...but how can I stop creating them?

Comment: do you still want the blend file?it is 15 mb

Comment: @VladIlisan - No problem at all.  15MB is not much - It's hard for me to say what's happening without seeing your workflow.

Comment: its processing...and i have problem doing the retopology at the mouth could you tell me few tips?or some advice?thanks again

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3562" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3562/)

Comment: and at back I can't unite the hole mesh

Comment: @VladIlisan - See my edit.  What you're attempting is probably one of the most difficult skills to master in Blender: creating custom, non-uniform, 3D topology.  It's easy to extrude faces during this process that aren't connected.  Usually it happens when I realize I should've done something differently and I go back to try to fix it.  That's probably all that happened.